# Using "the" before names and labels in quotations

Tags: definite-article

I wrote:

> Fig. 1 shows the user interface for creating a contextual rule. The rule shown is intended to eliminate [the?] *reference* section from the Wikipedia articles.

Do I need *the* before Wikipedia? Do I need it before *reference*? What if I write it as "reference" in quotation?

Here are other example:

> In this interface, “References” is the name of the rule
>
> In this rule, if the node’s tag is “H1” or “H2”, the algorithm updates **the** *curPart* value to  **“heading”** and **the** *curTitle* to the text extracted from the node (exText). We used the extracted text instead of the inner text because the node may contain some noise elements that must be excluded (e.g. **the** "Edit" link in the headings of Wikipedia articles)
>
> Finally, CR3 states if **the** *curTitle* is “References”, then the current node must be excluded from the extracted content (*References* section).

Italic names and names in quotations are some proper names or names I devised for some variables, but I am not sure which needs "the" and which doesn't. What is the rule?

Comment: Proper nouns do not need determiners. http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-use-articles-before-nouns

Comment: @JoeDark you mean none of them? Wikipedia, reference section in Wikipeda...?

Comment: @JoeDark I guess if I use as adjective I can use "ther", like the "reference" section or  the "curTitle" value...?

Comment: @Ahmed reference section is not a proper noun, Wikipedia is.  **The rule shown is intended to eliminate the reference section from Wikipedia articles.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few different situations going on here.

> Fig. 1 shows the user interface for creating a contextual rule. The rule shown is intended to eliminate the reference section from [the] Wikipedia articles.

- Here, *the* is needed before *reference* to modify *section:* "the section." (*Reference* here functions as an adjective modifying *section.*) Since *section* is a singular common noun, it needs an article (the type of word), as either "the section" or "a section." Since there is only one reference section per Wikipedia article, so *the* is the correct choice.
- Proper nouns like *Wikipedia* do not take articles (with a few exceptions, like *the Internet*). But here *Wikipedia* is functioning as an adjective, modifying *articles;* whether to use *the* depends on what is meant by *articles.*

  - If you mean to say that it can remove the reference section from any Wikipedia article or all Wikipedia articles, it should be "from Wikipedia articles" (no *a* or *an* since *articles* is plural; it would from "from *a* Wikipedia article" if *article* were singular).
  - If you mean to say that it can remove the reference section from a group of Wikipedia articles that has already been specified in what you're writing, use *the.* For example, if you've already described selecting the articles from which the  references section is to be removed, it would be "from the Wikipedia articles [that have already been selected]," with the part in brackets understood.

  The distinction doesn't depend on what the rule is actually capable of doing but on the context of your description. Considering just the sentence given, it sounds like it should be "from Wikipedia articles."

> In this rule, if the node’s tag is “H1” or “H2”, the algorithm updates the *curPart* value to “heading” and the *curTitle* to the text extracted from the node (exText). We used the extracted text instead of the inner text because the node may contain some noise elements that must be excluded (e.g. the "Edit" link in the headings of Wikipedia articles)

- "The curPart value" is fine. *The* goes with *value,* specifying that there is only one curPart value and that is what is being referred to ("the value"). The is the same rule as "the [reference] section," above. If there's no ambiguity (e.g., if curPart is just a string), you could just say "updates curPart to", treating curPart as a proper noun (which it functionally is).
- "Updates… curTitle to the text" is also fine. curTitle is treated as a proper noun.
- "Updates the *curPart* value to “heading” and the *curTitle*" should change for parallelism. Either use *the* and *value* with both (as currently done with curPart) or use neither *the* nor *value* (as currently done with curTitle).
- "The Edit link"—correct as it is. This is the same rule as "the reference section" and "the curPart value." *The* refers to *link,* so either *the* (if only one edit link, as there is) or *a* (if there could be more than one Edit link) is needed.

> Finally, CR3 states if the *curTitle* is “References”, then the current node must be excluded from the extracted content (References section).

- As in the previous paragraph, curTitle should be treated as a proper noun. Use "if curTitle is," "if the curTitle value is," or "if the value of curTitle" (by the same rules as above).

Comment: Thank you very much, Actually, *curTitle* is the name of a variable. Is it correct to say *the curTitle value*? or it should be *the curTitle's value* or even *the value of curTitle*?

Comment: Variable names function as proper nouns. There should be no _the_ applying to curTitle itself ("curTitle has a value of," not "The curTitle has"). In "the curTitle value," _the_ applies to _value,_ not breaking this rule. Generally, nouns (proper or common) referring to inanimate objects can be used as adjectives, as done here. Either "curTitle's value" (no _the,_ because _the_ would refer to curTitle) or "the value of curTitle" (_the_ refers to _value_) are equally correct. Which to choose is a matter of style, not grammar.